# Изменение id объекта при клике

Tags: javascript

Ребят, помогите, пожалуйста, решить вопрос.
Я могу использовать только js.

Нужно, чтобы при клике id объекта с классом = `navbar-menu` и с id = `menuburger` менялся на id = `menuclose`, а при втором клике менялся обратно на id = `menuburger`.

Нашел что-то подобное, но, блин, не хватает мозгов сделать под себя:

```
$('div').click(function(event) {
  //Удаляем старые id
  $('#menuburger').attr('id', null);
  $('#menuclose').attr('id', null);

  //Ставим новые
  $(this).parent().prev().attr('id', 'menuburger');
  $(this).attr('id', 'menuclose'); 
});`
```

Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Зачем менять id? Может, достаточно добавлять/убирать класс?

Comment: менять id однозначно плохая идея, судя по названиям этих id, нужно открывать/закрывать меню, и поэтому лучше менять класс

Comment: + вы говорите что можете использовать только js, а в вопросе у вас JQuery, так что же, всетаки можно использовать ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я верно понимаю, то вы собираетесь через изменение `id` управлять внешним видом меню и / или строить на этом логику вашего `js`-кода. Это плохая идея, так как она противоречит и стандартам html, и общепринятой практике написания подобных вещей. как вам уже верно советуют в комментариях к вашему вопросу, данную вещь нужно реализовывать через изменение классов. Собственно, как только вы углубитесь в реализацию логики своего кода, вы поймете, что менять `id` ваших элементов в `DOM` - это путь к неопределенности в коде с тем, что у вас чем является и что в данный момент должно делать.

Но, отвечая на ваш вопрос:

Во-первых, у вас в приведенном вами варианте не чистый `js`, а `js` с использованием библиотеки `JQUery`.

Во-вторых, приведенный вами код не рабочий, он меняет `id` не у этого же элемента. Вы можете проверить это тут:

```js
$('div').click(function(event) {
  //Удаляем старые id
  $('#menuburger').attr('id', null);
  $('#menuclose').attr('id', null);

  //Ставим новые
  $(this).parent().prev().attr('id', 'menuburger');
  $(this).attr('id', 'menuclose');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menuburger">test</div>
```

В-третьих, даже если поправить этот код, он все равно не будет рабочим, так как обработчики событий после таких выкрутасов перестанут понимать, что от них требуется - это произойдет опять же в силу того, что никто не предполагает такой логики приложений. Можете проверить это здесь:

```js
$('#menuburger.navbar-menu').click(function() {
  $(this).attr('id', 'menuclose');
});
$('#menuclose.navbar-menu').click(function() {
  $(this).attr('id', 'menuburger');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menuclose" class="navbar-menu">test</div>
```

В заключение, могу лишь еще раз посоветовать использовать для подобных вещей классы.

Comment: Спасибо большое!) Решил свой вопрос через классы!)

Answer (score 0):

Судя с вопроса, вам нужно именно скрывать/показывать меню, я конечно не большой эксперт по js, но id на странице должны быть уникальными (припустим, если у вас будет 10 таких менюшек, на странице, как поступать тогда с id ?), поэтому, для показывания/скрытия менюшек, смену id я бы использовать не стал, лучшим вариантом будет при клике добавить класс (пусть он зовется invisible), а при следующем клике его убрать.

Вот краткий пример кода на JS:

```js
document.getElementById("menuburger").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("test").classList.toggle("invisible");
});
```

```css
.invisible {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="menuburger">test it</button>

<div id="test" style="background-color:red">this is some menu or whatever</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему через z-index)
Спасибо большое всем, кто откликнулся!

```
`<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menuburger').on('click', function (){
        $('#menuclose').css('z-index','11');
    });

   $('#menuclose, #menuclosebg, #menucloselink').on('click', function (){
       $('#menuclose').css('z-index','9');
   })
});
</script>`
```